# How to get prints when using subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, printing, subprocess, popen

I have been working with using scripts such as

```
subprocess.Popen(f"py test.py hello &", shell=True, universal_newlines=True)
```

which will open the script test.py:

```
import time
import sys

while True:
   print(sys.argv[1])
   time.sleep(1)
```

However if I run multiply times etc

```
subprocess.Popen(f"py test.py hello &", shell=True, universal_newlines=True)
subprocess.Popen(f"py test.py world &", shell=True, universal_newlines=True)
subprocess.Popen(f"py test.py stackoverflow &", shell=True, universal_newlines=True)
```

that means that each of these runs will have its own sys.argv[1] value and will print out over and over again.

However my question is, I want to create a script where I call etc `py outprints.py test hello` *"All test.py with the argv of "hello"* should be printed and continue to print during the process
of `subprocess.Popen(f"py test.py hello &", shell=True, universal_newlines=True)`

I wonder if it is possible to do such a script which reads the outlogs of a script that is on in the background and see its outprint and if it is, what can I be able to do that?

Comment: If you use the `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` keyword argument to `Popen`, then the object returned by `subprocess.Popen` will have a property `stdout` that is a filehandle that you can read from. Also there is no point in using `&` inside the command because the whole point of `subprocess` is to manage processes that are running in the background. If you further launch background processes using `&` then you make it harder to control the process using for example the `kill` method.

Comment: Oh okey okey, make sense but where will I be able to read the stdout in that case? I can remove the & if its not needed aswell :) But I assume if I do some config with stdout, there is a way to get the prints or?

Comment: Just posted an answer putting this together for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of reading output from one of your subprocesses back into the main process.

```
import subprocess

proc = subprocess.Popen(["python", "test.py", "hello"],
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

# read 5 lines of output from the subprocess and then kill it
for i in range(5):
    line = proc.stdout.readline()
    print("The subprocess said ", line.decode())

proc.kill()
```

In your `test.py`, you should insert a statement to flush the output:

```
import time
import sys

while True:
   print(sys.argv[1])
   sys.stdout.flush()
   time.sleep(1)
```

This will ensure that the output data is available for reading immediately.  Otherwise you will be waiting a long time until you see any output because it will be held in a buffer.

Comment: It seems to work sort of what I want to do! however is it possible to create a script thar does just the code you had in ur for i in range(5) where you first look for the running script and then read the line out of it? Meaning that I will create a script and by the test.py and argv I would be able navigate to the correct running script and get the stdout out of it?

Comment: @ProtractorNewbie you can certainly have multiple subprocesses running, and for example you could store the objects returned by `Popen` in a list, and then you can obtain the relevant object from the list to interact with each one when wanted.  Knowing at any time _which_ subprocess to read a line from next, when you have several processes all producing output independently, is potentially a harder problem. You may need to ask a separate question about that once your code has got to that stage.

Comment: Got it! atleast a good start and thank you! Appreiciete that alot!